# when I singup to my website it said that it singup successfully but when I'm going to my data base it ain't showing nothing

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

when I'm singup my website I see in the url is says singup=success but whem I'm going to my data base I can't see the information I just typed in and send and for long time I can't understand what the problem is...
I checked the code couple times. I don't know what the problem can be.

sing up html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title id="title">MatukoCustom | הרשמה</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alef:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">

            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.HTML"><img src="images/logo.png" width="125px" ></a>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-btn">
                <a href="" class="btn-navbar-login" style="margin-left: 10px;">התנתק</a>
            </div>
            
            <nav>
                <ul id="MenuItems">
                    <li><a href="index.HTML"> בית</a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html">מוצרים </a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">תיק עבודות</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">אודות</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">צרו קשר</a></li>
                    <li><u><a href="login.html">משתמש</a></u></li>  
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <a href="cart.html" class="cart"><img src="images/cart.png" width="30px" height="30px">0</a>
            <img src="images/menu.png" class="menu-icon" onclick="menutoggle()">
        </div>
    </div>


    <!---------account page---------->
    <div class="account_page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <img src="images/image1.png" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-container">
                        <div class="form-btn">
                            <span onclick="register()">הרשמה</span>
                            <span onclick="login()">התחברות</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr id="Indicator">
                        <form id="LoginForm">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="שם משתמש">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="סיסמה">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn">התחברות</button>
                            <a href="">שכחתי את הסיסמה</a>
                        </form>

                        <form id="RegForm" action="singup.php" method="post">
                            <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="שם משתמש">
                            <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="אימייל">
                            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="סיסמה">
                            <input type="password" name="pwd-repeat" placeholder="חזור על הסיסמה">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="singup-submit">הרשמה</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--------footer---------->
<div class="fotter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="footer-col-2">
                <a href="index.HTML"><img src="images/logo-white.png"></a>
                <p>MatukoCustom היא אחת החנויות היחידות בארץ המציעות עיצובים אישיים<br>מכל הסוגים, מכובעים ועד נעליים, מדיוקנים ועד פאנקו פופ.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-col-3">
                <h3>קישורים מועילים</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="fotter-btn">קופונים</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="fotter-btn">תקנון</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="fotter-btn">מדינות החזרות</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="fotter-btn">הצטרף כחבר  מועדון</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-col-4">
                <h3>תעקבו אחרי</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="fotter-btn">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/matuko_artwroks/" target="_blank" class="fotter-btn">Instagram</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="fotter-btn">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="fotter-btn">Youtube</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <p class="copyright">זכויות יוצרים 2020 - שליו מתוקו</p>
    </div>
</div>

<!---------just for toggle menu--------->
<script>
    var MenuItems = document.getElementById("MenuItems");

    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";

    function menutoggle(){
        if(MenuItems.style.maxHeight == "0px")
            {
                MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "200px";
            }
        else
            {
                MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";
            }
    }

    var LoginForm = document.getElementById("LoginForm");
    var RegForm = document.getElementById("RegForm");
    var Indicator = document.getElementById("Indicator");
    var Title = document.getElementById("title");

        function register(){
            Title.text = "MatukoCustom | הרשמה"
            RegForm.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
            LoginForm.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
            Indicator.style.transform = "translateX(-50px)";
        }
        function login(){
            Title.text = "MatukoCustom | התחברות"
            RegForm.style.transform = "translateX(300px)";
            LoginForm.style.transform = "translateX(300px)";
            Indicator.style.transform = "translateX(-150px)";
        }
</script>
<script src="add-cart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the singup php code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['singup-submit'])) {

    require 'dbh.php';

    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
        header("Location: register.html?error=emptyfiled&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }
    elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username))  {
        header("Location: register.html?error=invalidmailuid");
        exit();
    }
    elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: register.html?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
        exit();
    }
    elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: register.html?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }
    elseif ($password !== $passwordRepeat) {
        header("Location: register.html?error=passowrdcheck&mail=".$email."&uid=".$username);
        exit();
    }
    else {

        $sql = "SELECT uidUsers From users WHERE uidUsers=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: register.html?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: register.html?error=usertaken&mail=".$email);
                exit();
            }
            else {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    header("Location: register.html?error=sqlerror");
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $emai, $hashedPwd);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    header("Location: login.html?singup=succcess");
                    exit();
                }

            }
        }

    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    
}
else {
    header("Location: register.html");
    exit();
}
```

database php code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "loginsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

data base code:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
idUsers int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
uidUsers TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
emailUsers TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
pwdUsers LONGTEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
For this statement I am not able to see any variables binded, have you done variables binding before executing query?

Comment: @Bhavana - They're binding the variables in the `else` block below (if the prepare was successful). They do have a typo on the `$email` variable though.

Comment: _“I can't understand what the problem is...”_ - the problem is that _you_ pretend it was a success, without actually _checking_ whether your database query succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $emai, $hashedPwd);`
May be a typo in this line (`email`)